# Where using "IS NULL"

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Im trying to retrieve a set of records using EF 4.3.1. I need to get all those records that have a NULL value in certain column.

I checked the database and many rows are null in that collumn, also the column is nullable. EF is doing something strange. Looking the profiler, it is generating the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
WHERE 1 = 0
```

My entity columns is declared as "int?"

I tried using the following conbinations but i get the same result:

```
dbset.Where(e=>e.MyNullableInt == null).ToList();
dbset.Where(e=>e.MyNullableInt.Equals(null)).ToList();
```

The only way that i can pass this strange behavior is load the full set, populate a variable and do the where after this step, which is very inneficient since it loads all the data.

Any ideas how to achieve this?.

Comment: UPDATE: I found the following ticket in Codeplex regarding a detected issue that affects EF Versions previous to EF 5.

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/178

They propose to use a comparison to workaround the problem, but in my case i do not use a variable, i need to actually filter using a null.

Anyone knows how to workaround this?

Comment: Are you sure you have defined the mapping as nullable?  Do you have a [Required] attribute on the field of the entity?

Comment: Yes, actually the column is a foreign key. The configuration of the entity was made using the fluent API.
I already checked and the database has many rows with null values in this column. 
If you get the whole set from EF it returns null's for those rows that does not have values on that columns and the id's for those rows that have. The problem occurs when you use the (x=>x.id == null) condition.

Migrating to the latest version of EF is not an option by now, since it will require me to do several testing in the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

Try This may this can Help U...

```
dbset.Where(e=> (e.MyNullableInt ?? -1) == -1).ToList();
```

Comment: It partially works. 
If you run dbset.Where(e=> (e.MyNullableInt ?? -1) == -1)... it will retrieve nothing.
If you run dbset.Where(e=> (e.MyNullableInt ?? -1) != -1)... it will retrieve those rows that are not equal to -1.

In SQL terms, the code is like this:
WHERE (-1 = NullableInt)

and...

WHERE (-1 <> NullableInt)

Appreciate your help.

Comment: In SQL Terms its Like where ISNULL(NullableInt,-1) = -1. I'm using it to retrieve data for my app and it works for me.

Comment: Maybe you are using a different version of EF. In my API the generated SQL is very different which is as follows "WHERE (-1 = [Extent1].[NullableInt])"

Answer (score 1):

Check your mapping as i have seen this happening when in mapping you are somehow making that field Required.

or in your database that field is not nullable.